# REST API Request mapping with @pathvariable does not fetch, throws not found error

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

I'm mapping an endpoint to fetch an object by it's ID from an array of Objects

this is my request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/items/{Id}", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public Item getItemById(@PathVariable("Id") String Id) throws NoSuchItem {
return ItemList.getItemById(Id);
}
```

this is my `getItemById` function in my `ItemList` class,

```
 private static ArrayList<Item> itemList;

 public static Item getItemById(String id) throws NoSuchItem {
    for(Item x:itemList){
         if(x.getId()== id)
          return x;
     }
     throw new NoSuchItem();
 }
```

this is the JSON representation of my `itemList` array which has 3 Item objects,

```
[
{
    "name": "Mars",
    "supplier": "Nestle",
    "weight": "1",
    "id": "mars",
    "location": null
},
{
    "name": "Kit Kat",
    "supplier": "Nestle",
    "weight": "1",
    "id": "kitkat",
    "location": null
},
{
    "name": "Double Decker",
    "supplier": "Nestle",
    "weight": "1",
    "id": "dd",
    "location": null
}
]
```

I want my `/items/{id}` endpoint to return only the desired Item, But it throws a 404 error, what am I doing wrong here?

PS- I'm sending my requests through POSTMAN

the cURl command for my postman request is as follows;

```
curl --location --request GET 'localhost:8082/items/mars'
```

Comment: Can you please share the `curl` command of your postman request? A 404 suggests that the wrong url is used for the query.

Comment: Please share your URL

Comment: I have updated it in the question :)

Comment: Is your server started without any issues, can you see the server logs and confirm? Are you able to invoke other endpoints in the same controller, please create one and see if that works?

Comment: yes my server starts without issues, and yes i have many other endpoints, even /items returns the json representation of the items, it  doesnt work only for the /items/{id} path

Comment: for clarification:  instead of `if(x.getId()== id)` use `x.getId().equals(id)` to compare.